# Installing Windows 7 on UX31A's GPT disk

Tags: windows, installation, gpt, asus-laptop, zenbook

There are a lot of Windows/GPT-related questions out there, but from what I've been reading these past hours, I seem to be doing the right thing... except, well, obviously not.

I'm trying to install a fresh Windows 7 Ultimate x64 on the Zenbook Prime (UX31A) which comes with a GPT partitioned disk. I created a USB install drive using FAT32, so that the Zenbook offers me 2 options to boot from it: UEFI and non-UEFI.

It's my understanding that if the Windows installer is booted in UEFI mode, it *should* be able to install Windows on a GPT partition. But I get the usual "*Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style*". Anybody has an idea what's going on there?

Comment: Are you able to modify the partition and set it to GPT in the installation process, like with previous versions?

Comment: I don't think so... when Windows asks what disk/partition it should be installed on, the only available tools are for deleting/creating/formatting partitions. The partition table is still a GPT one.

What I ended up doing was just to boot with Gparted, and recreating the whole disk as a MBR one.